# Maximal compact subgroup of SL(2,R)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups

I want to classify up conjugacy the compact subgroups of SL(2,R) (I need a proof)... Please help me.

Comment: And I want to prove that the Riemann hypothesis is true.

Comment: tbh wouldn't we all......

Answer (score 2):

Write $SL(2,R)=T SO(2,R)$ with $T$ the set of upper triangular matrices with determinant 1 and positive diagonal elements.
Now for $A \in T$, we have $(A^n)_{1,1}=(A_{1,1})^n$ so if $(A_{1,1})\neq 1$ the sequence $(A^n)_n$ will have hard time having a subsequence converging in $SL(2,R)$.
If $A_{1,1}=1$ then it follows that $A_{2,2}=1$ and in this case $(A^n)_{1,2}=nA_{1,2}$ so the above sequence has a converging subsequence iff $A_{1,2}=0$ that is $A=I$.

Comment: Why does this establish the claim?  If I consider $AB\in Sl(2,R)$ with $A\in T$ and $B\in SO(2,R)$ and try to run your argument, how do I conclude $A = I$?

Comment: Then $B^{-1}$ is in SO(2,R) thus $A=ABB^{-1}$ would be in the maximal compact subgroup

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!